# Importing Pantomime for sending email!

Tags: cocoa, email, import

I want to send an email from Cocoa in an asynchronous manner. I have downloaded Pantomime source code and compiled it, then got the framework from the build folder. I have added the Pantomime framework in my app. Now my problem is when I add the import satement like:

```
#import <Pantomime/Pantomime.h>
```

I got these build errors:

> `error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'RunLoopEvents'`
>
> `error: syntax error before 'RunLoopEventType'`
>
> `fatal error: method definition not in @implementation context`

All these errors are found in CWService.h, which is one of the files in the Pantomime framework header.

Can anyone suggest how can I import the header without build errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it doesn't know that you are on Mac OS X. I just looked into an old project and there I used

```
#define MACOSX
#include <Pantomime/Pantomime.h>
```

to include the Pantomime header. So you could try to #define MACOSX before importing the Pantomime header to see if this solves your problem.

Comment: Wow, That was great. I used this #define and those error no longer exists.
Thank you very very much for this most specific answer and your valuable time. :)